# Has at least one calendar day passend between now and a datetime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I have a timestamp like `new Date('2017-07-03T16:00:00.000')`

I need to compare this date to the current date (`new Date()` without arguments) and be able to tell whether at least one day has passed by date.
The time of the day does not play a role.

Here are a few examples:

**Example 1**
Old datetime: `2017-07-02T20:00:00.000`
Current datetime: `2017-07-03T16:00:00.000`
Returns `true` because the old date was 2nd of July 2017, the current one is 3rd of July 2017.

**Example 2**
Old datetime: `2017-07-02T20:00:00.000`
Current datetime: `2017-07-02T22:00:00.000`
Returns `false` because the old date was 2nd of July 2017 and the current one is 2nd of July 2017.

**Example 3**
Old datetime: `2017-07-02T20:00:00.000`
Current datetime: `2017-07-04T22:00:00.000`
Returns `true` because multiple days have passed since the 2nd of July 2017.

I can't come up with a simple way to do this without messing with the calendar (month-& year transitions, leapyear etc.) itself. Can you enlighten me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
compare=date=>(new Date()-(1000*60*60*24))>+new Date(date));
```

Simply check if current - 1day > old...

If you dont want 24 hours but rather last day, you can use modulo:

```
compare=date=>new Date()-(new Date()%(1000*60*60*24))>+new Date(date);
```

Comment: Ok but with this at least 24 hours need to be passed between both datetimes. I also want to return true when its a new day (e.g. compare time was at 6 PM yesterday, you check at 2 AM today --> returns true)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you can use module with Dates likes this

Answer (score 1):

```js
function oneDayHasPassed(date1, date2) {
  const year1 = date1.getFullYear();
  const year2 = date2.getFullYear();
  const month1 = date1.getMonth();
  const month2 = date2.getMonth();
  const day1 = date1.getDate();
  const day2 = date2.getDate();

  return year2 > year1 || (year1 === year2 && (month2 > month1 || month1 === month2 && day2 > day1));
}

const tests = [
  ['2017-07-02T20:00:00.000', '2017-07-03T16:00:00.000'],
  ['2017-07-02T20:00:00.000', '2017-07-02T22:00:00.000'],
  ['2017-07-02T20:00:00.000', '2017-07-04T22:00:00.000'],
];

tests.forEach(([d1, d2]) => console.log(oneDayHasPassed(new Date(d1), new Date(d2))));
```